# Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found

Tags: python, windows, fortran, anaconda, gfortran

I'm trying to install pyOpt in Python and I got this error :

> error: library algencan has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found

I'm using Anaconda on windows 7, I tried to install "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7", but I got the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should install a Fortran compiler, e.g. `gfortran` (via MinGW/Cygwin on Windows). See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) for details. A C++ compiler won't help here.

[MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) includes `gfortran` as part of the distribution, with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html), you need to install the package `gcc-fortran`.

After the installation, add the path to its binary to the system `PATH`.

Alternatively, you can purchase a commercial Fortran Compiler, e.g. from Intel.

Comment: after installing Cygwin, i couldn't use any command ( as: wget .. ), so how can install packages ?

Comment: During installation, you can search for and select additional packages. If you run the setup again, it will provide the same dialog to allow you to install additional packages. This will not re-install everything, just the new packages. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin) for details.

Comment: How do you find the path ?

Comment: `After the installation, add the path to its binary to the system PATH.` Where may this path ?